Evaluate $\lim_{\gamma \rightarrow \infty} \int_{[0,\gamma]} \int_0^1 (e^{-\int_0^{u} (1+f(x,\frac{\nu}{\gamma}) d\nu)} d\mu(x) \times du$

Let $\mu$ be a finite Borel measure on $[0,1]$, and suppose $f:[0,1]^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ is nonnegative, measurable, and $u \mapsto f(x,u)$ is continuous $\forall x$.  If $I_{\gamma}(f) := \int_{[0,\gamma]} \int_0^1 (e^{-\int_0^{u} (1+f(x,\frac{\nu}{\gamma}) d\nu}) d\mu(x) \times du)$, compute $\lim_{\gamma \rightarrow \infty} I_{\gamma}(f)$.

Attempt: Let $F_{\gamma}(x,u) := \int_0^u 1 + f(x,\frac{v}{\gamma}) d\nu$ be the exponent, and $f_{\gamma}(x,v) := 1+f(x,\frac{v}{\gamma})$ be its integrand.
i) Now, for fixed $x$, we note that the family $(v \mapsto f_{\gamma}(x,v))_{\gamma}$ converges locally uniformly to $1+f(x,0)$ by the continuity of the $x-$sections of $f$.
ii) Hence, for fixed $x \in [0,1]$ and $u \in [0,M)$, and $\gamma > \frac{M}{\delta}$, where $\delta \equiv \delta(x,M)$ is such that $|v| < \delta \implies |f(x,v) - f(x,0)| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{M}$, we have that,
$| \int_0^{u} 1 + f(x,\frac{v}{\gamma}) - u(1+f(x,0)| \leq $ $ \int_0^u |f(x,\frac{v}{\gamma}) - f(x,0)| dx < \int_0^M \epsilon/M = \epsilon $.
That is, $(u \mapsto F_{\gamma}(x,u))_{\gamma}$ is locally uniformly convergent sequence, with limit $F(x,u) := u(1+f(x,0))$.
iii) Now, given $I_{\gamma} (f) = \int \int e^{-F_\gamma(x,u)} \chi_{[0,\gamma]}(u) \chi_{[0,1]}(x) d\mu(x) du$, note that $F_\gamma(x,u) \geq u$ as $f \geq 0$, so that $e^{-F_\gamma(x,u)} \leq e^{-u}$. But then, $|I_{\gamma}| \leq \int_0^{\infty} \mu(X) e^{-u} du = \mu(X) < \infty$, i.e., we have a dominating function.
Hence, $\lim_{\gamma} I_{\gamma}(f) = \int \int \lim_{\gamma \rightarrow \infty}e^{-F_\gamma(x,u)} \chi_{[0,\gamma]}(u) \chi_{[0,1]}(x) d\mu(x) du $. By continuity of the exponential + $ \lim {(\prod)}= \prod (\lim)$, we get $I_{\gamma} = \int \int e^{-\lim_{\gamma \rightarrow \infty} F_\gamma(x,u)} \chi_{[0,\infty)}(u) \chi_{[0,1]}(x) d\mu(x) du  $.
Finally by (ii), we get that $I_{\gamma} = \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^1 e^{-u(1+f(x,0))} d\mu(x) du $.
Question: Is this argument valid? I'm in particular unsure about step (iii). Also, I was curious if $(u \mapsto F_{\gamma}(x,u))_{\gamma}$ is locally uniformly convergent (if correct) is at all of help here.
